# Scale To property doesn't worke properly in xamarin.android

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am using 'ScaleTo' property for showing little animation in the screen, It work's greatly in xamarin.Ios but in android not works good. What I am tried is I have taking two images and each 30000 sec I am replace with other image.

Here is the sample code:

```
 Private async void SampleAnimation()
 {
     TestImage.Source = "ImageOne.png";
     await TestImage.ScaleTo(1.1, 3000, Easing.Linear);
     await TestImage.ScaleTo(1, 2);

     TestImage.Source = "Imagetwo.png";
     await TestImage.ScaleTo(1.1, 3000, Easing.Linear);
     await TestImage.ScaleTo(1, 2);
     RepeatLoop();
  }

  private async void RepeatLoop()
  {
     await SampleAnimation();
  }
```

In my xaml page image is added and in behind code load background image method is called in constructor. What my problem is after completion of first image animation, fliping the screen with white, white screen is appeared little amount of time between image inserting from imageone to imagetwo but it work's in ios without any problem, Only I am getting issue in andorid. Please suggest any idea upon this.

Comment: Those methods should be refactored to return `async Task`. Try to avoid using `async void` as much as possible.

Comment: Hi Nkosi, Thanks for your help. I have tried with removing those 'async task ' and 'async void' in methods but when I run like this doesn't show any images in the screen. it show's blank screen and I again tried with above mentioned code then images are appeared.